# ReactJS: updating props - turning a 17 object array of 2 key:value pairs into one with 3 key:value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, prop, ag-grid-react

I'm fairly new/junior to front end programming but I'm helping another to build a web UI for an application. For the most part, I've learnt enough to have a basic idea of what everything does, although I'm trying to add a feature which is a bit difficult.

Long story short, I have two ag-grids (using reactJS). The main one holds data and can be filtered, and I'm trying to make a second one that not only holds the column names from the main one but also as dynamically list the filters that were applied. This second grid is like an assistant/helper grid for the user

My understanding helped me get half way through implementing this so far (I've managed to populate the second ag-grid with all the column headers from the main grid).

The column headings data were stored and picked up from props. something similar to:

rowData : this.props.report.view.columns

if you run console.log(this.props.report.view.columns) (I'm using the console from chrome developer tools), you will see an array of 17 objects which hold column information. Structure shown below:

```
report: Object
|
--view: Object
  |
  --columns: Array(17)
    |
    --0: Object
    |  |
    |  -- field: "testColumn"
    |     headerName: "testColumn"
    |
    --1: Object
    --2: Object
    --3: Object
.
.
.   
    --16: Object
```

I'll just say this looks like an array of 17 objects, each holding two key:value pairs. What I want to do is add a third keyvalue pair

I have another prop that gives key:value pairs of only columns that have filters applied (i.e. columnName:blah , filter:blahh where the column names are stored under a different key name).

the pseudo code I plan to implement goes something like this:

```
For EACH element in the 17 Object array (this.props.report.view.columns)
    if headername = columnName (i.e. from column from filter prop)
THEN
    add new key:value pair headerName:filter; to that object element
ELSE 
    add new key:value pair headerName:''; (an empty value) to that object
```

What I will end up with is changing this 17 object array of 2 key:value pairs, to a 17 object array with 3 key value pairs
Is something like this possible? If so can I get some advice?
I'm a bit worried the whole plan I used is wrong. My senior colleague suggested I used a different plan using callbacks but I didn't see how that would be possible without major code changes (which is why I stuck to my intuition)

Comment: Do you want to change the existing `columns` array or create a new array? Also, you say you want to add `headerName` as a property, but `headerName` is *already* a property of the objects in the `columns` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `map` method ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
const data = [
  {a: 7, b: 0},
  {a: 4, b: 7},
  {a: 9, b: 6},
  {a: 1, b: 7},
];

const newData = data.map(currObj => ({...currObj, c: 0}));

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: This looks very promising. When testing it out i had to remove the three dots: console.log(this.props.report.view.columns); 
var newData = this.props.report.view.columns.map(currObj => ({currObj, filter:''}));
console.log(newData);
The proof in concept is there, although what happened is instead of an array object holding the 2 keyvalue pairs the object now holds currObj which holds the 2 pairs i.e. access now this.props.report.view.columns.[0].currObj.headerName and the filter keyvalue pair is not in the array but one level higher at this.props.report.view.columns.[0]

Comment: seems like understanding how this mapping function works will be the answer to getting all the keyvalue pairs on the same level

Comment: AHH. solved it. Thought it would be a tricky referencing issue but was a lot simpler than i expected haha. While googling your map function i saw an article which just uses forEach. I modified my example code and it works now! thank you for your help.   var newData = this.props.report.view.columns;
  newData.forEach(function(element) {
   element.filter = '';
  });

Comment: While my example works, I will need forEach twice when implementing the actual thing. Is this the advantage map has over forEach?